# Custom route class

Tags: symfony1, symfony

In symfony 1.4 you could define a custom route class, where you override the generation of url with custom logic, for example:

```
custom:
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                Custom
    prefix_path:          /custom/category/:category_id
    column:               id
    route_class:          CustomDoctrineRoute

class CustomDoctrineRoute extends sfDoctrineRoute
{
  public function generate($params, $context = array(), $absolute = false)
  {
    if (!isset($params['category_id'])) {
      $params['category_id'] = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParameter('category_id');
    }

    return parent::generate($params, $context, $absolute);
  }

}
```

This allows to write `url_for('custom_show', array('id'=> $object['id']))` and not bother about context dependent parameters (category_id).

How do you approach this is symfony2?

Comment: Here I've solved similar problem by overriding UrlGenerator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877806/symfony2-use-object-to-set-route-parameters

Answer (score 3):

I can think of 2 approaches to this. The first, and simplest, is to extend the Router class with your own and tell symfony to use your class in your parameters.yml or config.yml:

```
parameters:
    router.class: Company\CoreBundle\Routing\MyCustomRouter
```

There's a more powerful (read: complicated) solution which allows you to define more dependencies on your router class by overriding or extending the whole router **service**. There is a bundle that does this called [BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle) which you can look at to see how it's done.

Specifically, notice the [CompilerPass](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Compiler/OverrideRoutingCompilerPass.php) where they replace the default `router` service with their own. You then have to implement the [RouterInterface](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouterInterface.html) in your own router class. In this particular bundle they [inject the original default router](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing.xml#L16) (after having renamed it in the compiler pass).