# Symfony2 Service and Trait Best Practices for small chunks of code

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2 (could apply to other frameworks too) are there any factually based best practices defined for when to put a small chunk of reusable code in a trait as oppose to a service (or even in a model)?

e.g. scenario:
I had a small piece of code which modified a url slightly (added a specific port based on the current environment and machine). It was used by several controllers. I was told this would be best in a trait as a service would be overkill because it was only a few lines of code and there was only one parameter being passed to the function (the url).

Symfony2 manual defines a service as:

> "a generic term for any PHP object that performs a specific task."

There may be some subjective opinions here, but the question guidelines say:

> Great subjective questions inspire answers that explain “why” and
>   “how” and Great subjective questions insist that opinion be backed up
>   with facts and references

And that is what I am looking for. Factual reasons why or why not to use a trait over a service for a small chunk of code.

**Update**
A great suggestion has been: traits aren't easy to test whereas services are

Comment: This question is primary opinion-based and violates stackoverflow's rules for questions but i see some public interest aswell :/ Try to avoid traits as they aren't testable and can't be used in projects that use PHP <5.4. Adding a port can be achieved using the routing component ... If you need additional logic consider a custom **[url-generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9016324/1832745)** or a kernel **[event-listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)** (i.e. listening to `kernel.response`) that adds the port to your urls.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I have refactored my question slightly ;)

Comment: could you add a code example please? Nobody know's how you're currently generating that *url* and where/why you are using it afterwards.

Comment: It was a very complicated security based scenario involving allowing the server machine to access a url behind an oauth implementation for pdf generation (which used a binary on the server (wkhtmltopdf)). The specific port example would be better left for a different question. For this question I am interested in fact based arguments for when to use a trait over a service (or vice versa). Your point about testing is a very good one here I believe.