# URL value missing in Adress Bar if they match default values

Tags: symfony, url, routes

I use Symfony2 and when I ask for an URL throught a link in twig I have some of the value of the URL that desapear from the URL Adress Bar if they match the default values

Exemple of what I get and what I expect from the URL:

```
www.mywebsite.com/16                       // this is what I get
www.mywebsite.com/16                       // OK if I do not have value in the link
www.mywebsite.com/16/TitleUnknown/EN/FR    // this is what I expect if I DO have EN and FR as value for the URL in my link
```

Here the Router:

```
SeeArticle:
  path:     /{id}/{article_titre}/{language1}/{language2}
  defaults: {_controller: BlogBundle:Blog:seearticle,
          article_titre: titleUnknown,
          language1: EN,
          language2: FR }
```

For instance the following link won't show the default value in the adress bar. Is there a way to display those value?

```
<a href="{{ url('SeeArticle', {'id': 16, 'language1': 'EN', 'language2': 'FR' }) }}">
  mylink
</a>
```

Comment: You misunderstood the point of default parameters. Those default values are assumed if nothing is passed and are not appended automatically...

Comment: Yes I know that Jovan. In some cases I do not provide those value in the link and I am happy that they give me the default URL based on the default value. But in some other cases the link has values.... which happen to be equal to the default values, then I would like the adress bar to show those values.

Comment: And no errors when you render that link without apostrophes around EN, FR ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the apostrophes in my question. they are not missing in my code

Comment: You will need a custom `UrlGenerator`. Related SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877806/symfony2-use-object-to-set-route-parameters/9016324#9016324