# How to register event listener between session and router listeners?

Tags: events, symfony, listener

I want to register my listener for `kernel.request` after Session listener has already fired but Router listener hasn't (so that in my listener I can already use the session, but in case the route is not found it is fired nonetheless). I read that it's possible to manipulate the order in which listeners fire by setting `priority`, however it seems that those 'standard' Symfony listeners all fire with default priority.

So is there any way / how can I register listeners between those provided by Symfony?

Comment: I just realized that I can make my listener top-priority (255) and just pass `@session` service to it (so no need to wait for `SessionListener` to attach session to request), however it's still interesting to me how to manipulate the order of those predefined listeners.

Comment: If you are interested in handling routing then this may be helpful: [11364778/custom-routing-with-symfony-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364778/custom-routing-with-symfony-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can gain acces to the priorities of listener in this way:

```
 php app/console container:debug listener_service_name
```

You should get a detailed output and under tags you can see the priority if it a `kernel.event_listener`. If it's a `kernel.event_subscriber` you have to look in the corresponding class into the `getSubscribedEvents()` method. The second array parameter is the priority.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! So the problem was that I did not know where to look for priority of subscribers.

Answer (score 1):

By trial and error I discovered that RouterListener has priority of 31 or 32, and SessionListener has priority of 127 or 128. Therefore if I use any priority from 32 to 127 inclusively, I'll get my listener run between these two.

Now I wonder if there's any way to dump priorities of listeners or look them up.

Comment: It's kind of buried: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html#kernel-event-listener Search for 'Core Event Listener Reference'.  It would be nice to have a console command that lists these.  Have not found one yet.